# Recursively change directory python

Tags: python, os.walk

I am trying to write a program that can rename directories based on a certain keyword that appears inside the text files inside each of the directories after the part "Keyword:" in the files. So for Case003 below the orange.txt and cow.txt files both contain the same keyword that will rename their parent directory. This part is simple enough to do and not what I need right now, but the directory structure is what's making it difficult for me to implement this. This is the directory structure

```
   Project_Folder
    ├── Case001
    │   └── asdf422345112323423
    │       └── puppy.txt
    ├── Case002
    │   ├── jjasdfjtnqn3881847471
    │   │   └── apple.txt
    │   └── jtnjjqjqjwkwktjjthqj
    │       └── banana.txt
    └── Case003
        └── asdfasdfntjejqk21244
            ├── herwerhqkethf4443434
            │   ├── orange.txt
            │   └── cow.txt
            └── jdjdjafjejqjqyttjdjak
                └── cat.txt
```

I think I need to use `os.walk` here, but I'm struggling with how to make it so that it only changes the name of the parent directory since the generator of `os.walk` includes all of the directories and subdirectories inside the directory passed to `os.walk`. Is there a good way to call only the parent directories that contain `.txt` files?

If this helps clarify things, for Case003 the output of the code would look like this assuming the Keyword inside the text files is `Plane` and `Island` in the respective parent directories.

```
    └── Case003
        └── asdfasdfntjejqk21244
            ├── Plane
            │   ├── orange.txt
            │   └── cow.txt
            └── Island
                └── cat.txt
```

(Tree diagram created with ASCII tree generator for Visual Studio, which can be found [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aprilandjan.ascii-tree-generator)

Answer (score 0):

As you traverse the directory tree with `walk`, you always have the entire path available to you.  For instance, when you open `orange.txt`, you have access to the fully-qualified path `Project_Folder/Case003/asdfasdfntjejqk21244/herwerhqkethf4443434/orange.txt`.  All you need do is to process this string.  Lop off the file name and its parent directory, and what you have left is exactly the name of the directory you need to rename.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Hmm ok. I seem to be having some trouble indexing into the filelist in the os.walk output. Can you check this out https://www.codepile.net/pile/a0GrPV7E and see what you think?

Comment: I'm afraid not.  That would be well outside the operation of Stack Overflow.  Please post as a valid follow-on question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk). It returns a generator that yields a 3-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`. It will recursively walk through all subdirectories, so you only need to look at the filenames.

If you post the code you've attempted in the OP, we work with you better.

```py
import os

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('Project Folder'):
    # check the files for the keyword that you want to rename the parent to
    if filenames:
        for f in filenames:
            # read the txt file and get the keyword
            # rename the parent directory based on the keyword
            filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
```